# NPM on new Mac with transferred files from my previous linux system. Problem with npm start on VS CODE terminal

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, npm, visual-studio-code

**Hey people...transferred some working js files from old linux to my new macbook air. Upon trying to start my files with NPM start in the vs code terminal, I'm getting this error: (please help!)**

```
Galias-MacBook-Air:react-nextagram Guy$ npm start

react-nextagram@0.1.0 start /Users/Guy/Desktop/Next Academy/react-nextagram
react-scripts start

sh: /Users/Guy/Desktop/Next Academy/react-nextagram/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: cannot execute binary file
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! react-nextagram@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-nextagram@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Guy/.npm/_logs/2019-01-24T01_15_13_056Z-debug.log
Galias-MacBook-Air:react-nextagram Guy$
```

Comment: You mean you copied the entire node modules directory from you Ubuntu machine to your Mac? That won't work, npm compiles some C modules to binary, those are not cross system compatible. Delete node modules dir and run npm install

Answer (score 0):

Me too. I migrate from Ubuntu 18.04 to OSX Catalina. This is how I solve :

Delete your node_modules and `npm install` or `npm install -s`
Problem is inside your node_modules

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have compiled dependencies. One or more of the packages you use on your application need to be compiled against the OS you are going to run them in. To fix this, you can try one of the options bellow:

This will rebuild everything against your current OS.

`npm rebuild`

**Or**

you can do a clean install.

`rm -rf node_modules && npm install`